# Android save own data to embedded secure element

Tags: android, android-studio, security, keystore, android-keystore

I am working with Android Keystores (University project) at the moment.
As far as I know it is possible to store keys generated in the app in the secure element (hardware). Does anyone know of an option where I can store self-generated data (for example, keys that are not generated in the app) in the embedded secure element?

I also understood that NFC data can also be stored in the embedded secure element. Would it be possible to store self-generated data here?

I stumble over the open mobile api again and again, but currently get no further.
I am glad about every hint and contribution.

Many greetings
volta

Comment: You can import cryptographic keys (in decrypted or encrypted form) in the [AndroidKeystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)  which is backed by a hardware security elements on modern phones.